# How to Burtonize my water

Tags: water

I am participating in the AHA Big Brew day and the beer we'll be making is their [English IPA](http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/EastIndiaPaleAleSingleMash) part of this recipe requires modifying my water to be like Burton on the Trent water.

Calcium (Ca) - 268 ppm
Magnesium (Mg) - 62 ppm
Sodium (Na) - 30 ppm
Sulfate (SO4) - 638 ppm
Chloride (Cl) - 36 ppm
biCarbonate (HCO3) - 141 ppm
pH - 8.33

I've looked up my water ([Winnipeg, MB [PDF]](http://www.winnipeg.ca/waterandwaste/pdfs/water/waterQuality2009.pdf)) and it has 
Calcium (Ca) - 21.4 ppm
Magnesium (Mg) - 6 ppm
Sodium (Na) - 2 ppm
Sulfate (SO4) - ??? ppm
Chloride (Cl) - 5? ppm
biCarbonate (HCO3) - ??? ppm
pH - 7.48

I've never done this before, and I sucked at high school chemistry so I'm slightly nervous about modifying my water, but I'd love to start trying it.

So, how do I burtonize my water? What are the required materials? How do I determine how much/little to add? Anything else I should know?

Comment: I have wondered the same thing. Great Q. and great link Denny.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easy way is to download Martin Brungard's excellent brewing water software "[Bru'n Water](https://sites.google.com/site/brunwater/)" and follow the steps for Burton water in it.

Comment: Holy cow, that's an awesome find - thanks much.

Comment: at first glance that looks incredible. I'll check it out more throughly tonight

Comment: Martin is a professional water engineer and has done work with breweries.  The man knows his water.